# Is a python `abstract property` that returns an abstract class an example of the Factory Pattern

Tags: python-3.x, oop, design-patterns, observer-pattern, factory-pattern

I need to document my design, in particular, the design patterns used, and would like to use the standard terminology.

From [Refactoring Guru](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/factory-method/python/example), "Factory Method defines a method, which should be used for creating objects instead of direct constructor call. Subclasses can override this method to change the class of objects that will be created".

I have a `CraneInterface` class with an abstract method, and the signature of this method enforces that its return type is an implementation of an `AxisInterface`. Essentially, subclasses of `CraneInterface`  "override this method to change the class of objects that will be *created*". The only diference with my version is that it does not necessarily "*create*" a new instance, it could also return one that already exists. Is this still the Factory Pattern? And if not, does this design pattern have a common name?

i.e: A traditional factory looks like this:

```
class IAnimal(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def speak(self):
        pass

class Dog(IAnimal):
    #overide
    def speak(self):
        print('Woof')

class Cat(IAnimal):
    #overide
    def speak(self):
        print('Meow')
    
class AnimalFactory(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def make_animal(self) -> IAnimal:
        pass

class CatFactory(AnimalFactory):
    #overide
    def make_animal(self) -> IAnimal:
        return Cat()

class DogFactory(AnimalFactory):
    #overide
    def make_animal(self) -> IAnimal:
        return Dog()
```

My code looks more like this:

```
class AnimalFactory2(ABC):
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def animal(self) -> IAnimal:
        pass

class CatFactory2(AnimalFactory2):

    def __init__(self):
        self.__cat = Cat()

    #overide
    @property
    def animal(self) -> IAnimal:
        return self.__cat

class DogFactory2(AnimalFactory2):

    def __init__(self):
        self.__dog = Dog()    
    
    #overide
    @property
    def animal(self) -> IAnimal:
        return self.__dog
```

Does the second example use the Factory Pattern? Does it have a different name or even have a name at all? The main difference is that it does not create a new instance each time it is called.

*Extra info:*

In my actual code, I have a 3 axis `CraneInterface` class that has abstract methods for all the ways you can interact with a crane. It is implemented by a `CraneSimulator` and a `CraneOpcuaClient` that actually talks to a real crane. The original design of the simulator implemented the abstract method inside the `CraneSimulator` class, however, this had lots of duplicated code, as every function of the crane was repeated for each of the 3 axes. To solve this, I created an `AxisSimulation` class which had methods to interact with it, and then there are 3 instantiations inside the `CraneSimulator`, and the implementations of the `CraneInterface` abstract methods simply forward the request to one of the 3 axis objects.

The problem was that the `CraneInterface` also needed the ability to notify "observers" whenever the state of the crane changed, for example, a position or temperature change. I.e the `CraneInterface` needed to have a function `add_on_x_position_changed_callback(self, callback: Callable[[Position],None])`. To do this, the `CraneInterface` had properties with custom setters that notified a list of observers whenever the value was set. By putting the `AxisSimulation` inside the `CraneSimulator` the properties had moved out of the `CraneInterface`, and the `add_on_changed_callback` methods of the `CraneInterface` would no longer work.

So to solve this, the `CraneInterface` had an abstract property to return an abstract `AxisInterface` class (like the `AnimalFactory2` example). The `AxisInterface` then had the observable properties with a custom setter (and methods to add observers), so that users of the `CraneInterface` can add observers to the data.

I know that the "observable" part is an example of the Observer pattern, but is the deferring of the type of Axis implementation returned, an example of the Factory Pattern?

Thanks.